# If a node module includes its own package-lock.json, is that ignored/overridden by the parent package-lock.json?

Tags: npm, node-modules, eslint, npm-install

I have a repository that has a bunch of peer dev dependencies (this repo is a standalone eslint config, like airbnb).

If I used this in a another project as a node module (importing it through github, not retrieving it through npm), will the `package-lock.json` file that is generated in this module be used in the callers project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Per [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#description), `package-lock.json` files "will be ignored if found in any place other than the toplevel package."

If you want lock-file behavior in a dependency, use [a shrinkwrap file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/shrinkwrap-json) instead.

Assuming you are still installing with the `npm` client, the fact that you are retrieving the package from somewhere other than the npm registry doesn't affect this behavior.